# Create 2D cutout of 3D object using geometry nodes

Tags: 3d-printing, mathematics, geometry-nodes

Create 2D cutout of 3D object using geometry nodes.

I'm trying to create a 2D cutout from a geometry node generated 3D cone (**and make it procedural**)

**See red arrow pointing to 2D image that I'm trying to create and make 3D printed using very thin layers** (which will be bendable)

The video I was following. https://youtu.be/JUgRPUSxoEc

[image: img1]

My thoughts were to use geometry nodes to have people customize their own cone dimensions and have the 2D cutout be generated.

Example / My thoughts:

1. 3D Cone generated from Cone node

[image: img2]

2. 2D cutout generated from the Arc node (**so it can be 3D printed by extruding in Z direction for depth**)

[image: img3]

**I'm having some trouble with the math conversions and what the correct start/sweep angles should be**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following setup should do exactly what you want:

[image]
[image]

[image]

Theses are our base values:

Height of the cylinder = $h$
Radius of the circle = $r_1$

The formulas for this are:

Arc Length (the circumference of the circle): $b = 2 * r_1 * \pi$
Radius of the arc: $r_2 = \sqrt{r_1² + h²}$
Arc angle: $\alpha = \frac{b}{r_2} $

Comment: Hi @q!  Maybe misinterpreting the brief, apologies if so, (I make myself available to be stomped all over.. :D ) ..but don't we need a bit of Pythagoras here? The arc-radius of a cone base-radius 1, height 2, is sqrt(5), [not 3](https://imgur.com/a/4AR85Wd).

Comment: @RobinBetts Haha, Yes, you are absolutely right. It was already very late yesterday and while shortening the nodes, I probably swept some important things of our friend Pythagoras under the carpet. :D ...I'll correct this unforgivable mistake shortly....

Comment: @RobinBetts The answer has been corrected. Thanks for reading carefully and for pointing out the error instead of downvoting right away! I will be more careful in the future when shortening the nodes down ;-)

Comment: I would _never_ downvote without  an explanation, and before attempting a resolution, unless a blatant abuse. I was in a hurry, too. You got my +1 before I looked at the nodes and thought: 'hang on a minute...' :)